# How Extension and Plugin works

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite, findersync

I am creating a FinderSync Extension along with my containing application.
I got following issues.

1.My extension can not access folders or files in local machine.(my extension is sandboxed).

2.On building the containing application i got extension.appex in plugin folder.But its not working in finder and not listed in extension(in system preferences) on running containing application.

Please explain how did extensions starts on installing and running containing app?

Please help to overcome this stuck.

Thanks in advance for your valuable time!

Answer (score 1):

1) Sandboxed applications cannot access files and folders outside its own containers. You can add [temporary entitlements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html) like com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write, but if you're submitting your app to the App Store, it may get rejected.

2) Are there any logs in the Console as to why the extension failed to startup? When you debug from XCode, be sure to run the scheme for your extension and not your parent app.

Comment: @dejuknow- When debugging from XCode it shows only build success massage. No other logs in console. There is lot of logs i provided but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find out the right solution to my second(2) question but I can prevent it from such  scenario.

1.Stop debugging from Xcode Product->Stop option.

2.Make sure that the extension is unchecked from System Preference->Extension before debug.